# Append org-agenda-files with files of another directory

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

So i try to create a list of string in the form

```
"a" "b" "c"
```

This is a list of files which i want to pass to `org-agenda-files`
As for now this looks like this

```
(setq org-agenda-files "~/.tasks.org")
```

Now i need to add some files coming from a directory. i can get those with `directory-files-recursively "~/orgroam/daily" "\\`[^.].*\.org\'"`. this will return lets say` ("~/b" "~/c")`.

The problem comes when i try to concatenate the "a". What i have tied so far is

```
(list "~/.tasks.org" (mapconcat #'identity (directory-files-recursively "~/orgroam/daily" "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'") " "))
```

and

```
(concat "~/.tasks.org " (mapconcat #'identity (directory-files-recursively "~/orgroam/daily" "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'") " "))
```

but this returns `"a" "b c"` and `"a b c"`

Another thing i tried out is to add the result of `directory-files-recursively` after the `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/.tasks.org"))` using `add-to-list`. in this case i get `Wrong type argument: stringp, ("~/orgroam/daily/2022-01-19.org" "~/orgroam/daily/2022-01-28.org"....)`

Does anyone have a suggestion to achieve the desired output for `org-agenda-files`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include all org files from another directory, you can:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/.tasks.org"
                         "~/orgroam/daily/"))
```

If you still want to append files, you can:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files (append
                        '("~/.tasks.org")
                        (directory-files-recursively "~/Documents/Org/notes/" "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'")))
```

As a friendly reminder, numerous Org files may cause Agenda to be very slow, you can refer to this [blog](https://d12frosted.io/posts/2021-01-16-task-management-with-roam-vol5.html).